# gcc-ar: Error running /usr/bin/ar: vfork

Tags: linux, gcc, gnu

As the title says: my ar fails on a vfork() and consumes all resources for a minute or so, before exiting.

I see the same for both GCC 7.3 and GCC 4.8

Binutils v2.30

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Any ideas how to figure out what is going on?

Comment: I downgraded binutils-2.30-15ubuntu1 and it seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: same problem. when using `ps -u` in another terminal we can see thousands of repeating `/usr/bin/ar --plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/liblto_plugin.so --plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/liblto_plugin.so .......`